# Why can't I console log/stringify a whole array on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so I am struggling trying to access a -somewhat- complex Array on Javascript.

On a simple way, I have an array like so:

```
globalForm['prop1'] = anotherArray[];
globalForm['prop2'] = yetAnotherArray[];
```

If I try to:

```
console.log(globalForm);
//-or-
JSON.stringify(globalForm)
```

I get an empty Array [] or an empty JSON object.

But if I do this:

```
console.log(globalForm['prop1']);
//-or-
JSON.stringify(globalForm['prop1'])
```

I actually get its contents.

Am I doing something wrong/stupid at trying to log or stringify the whole array? What I am trying to achieve is to create a complex JSON object from that array.

This is my actual code:
For prop1:

```
var completedWeights = [];
globalForm['CompletedFormPhoto'] = images;

var radio_groups = {}
$(".weightRadio:radio").each(function(){
    radio_groups[this.name] = true;
});
for(group in radio_groups){
    thisGroup = $(".weightRadio:radio[name="+group+"]:checked");
    if_checked = !!thisGroup.length;
    completedWeights.push({'IdWeight':thisGroup.attr('name'), 'Value':thisGroup.val()});
}
globalForm['CompletedFormWeight'] = completedWeights;
```

For prop2 (this actually executes before generating prop1):

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var idImg = Date.now();
    var currentImageObj =[];
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;
    var addedImage = document.createElement('div');
    addedImage.className = 'addedImage';

    if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = reader.result;
            img.id = idImg;
            addedImage.appendChild(img);

            var ind = img.src.indexOf(',/9j/') + 5;
            currentImageObj["Photo"] = img.src.substr(ind);

            images[idImg] = currentImageObj;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        console.log(images);
    } else {
        addedImage.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
    }
    addComment = document.createElement('a');
    addComment.className = "btn btn-default btn-block addComment";
    addComment.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
    addComment.setAttribute("data-target", "#myModal");
    addComment.text = "Agregar Comentario";
    addComment.id = idImg;

    addedImage.appendChild(addComment);
    fileDisplayArea.appendChild(addedImage);
});
```

Some examples of the actual content of the arrays:
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you create `globalForm` as an Array. Arrays in JavaScript only understand *integer* indices. Since they are still objects, you can of course give them named properties, but those won't fill the array. The equivalence of dot-notation and bracket indexing in JavaScript might have misled you there.

So either you use just numbers like this:

```
globalForm=[]
globalForm[1]=["whatever"]
globalForm[2]=["etc"]

console.log(globalForm)
=> [undefined, ["whatever"], ["etc"]]
```

(note that array indices are zero-based)

… Or if you're looking for something more like a mapping between names and values, you should simply use a (non-Array) object:

```
globalForm={}
globalForm["prop1"]=["whatever"]
globalForm["prop2"]=["etc"]

console.log(globalForm)
=> {prop1: ["whatever"], prop2:["etc"]}
```

Comment: Totally did the trick. I was declaring globalForm as a simple array. Changing its definition to {} worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is perfectly fine there is no reason to stringify complex object

Also worth noting its not a json object, its a javascript object, or a json string that describe an object.

Take a  look at this:

```
var object = {
    prop1 : 'what ever',
    prop2 : 'whatever to',
    prop3 : [
        {a : "a", b: 'b' },
        {a : "a", b: [
            {a : "a", b: 'b' },
            {a : "a", b: "b" },
            {a : "a", b: 'b' }
        ]},
        {a : "a", b: 'b' }
        ]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
// outPuts : {"prop1":"what ever","prop2":"whatever to","prop3":[{"a":"a","b":"b"},{"a":"a","b":[{"a":"a","b":"b"},{"a":"a","b":"b"},{"a":"a","b":"b"}]},{"a":"a","b":"b"}]}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/or6gj92y/

Tip: when i run into something i have an issue with i would try a small version of it in something like jsfiddle.net or plunker for a "sanity check" hope that helps